# How do I inherit only 1 class in Sphinx?

Tags: python, inheritance, python-sphinx

How do I inherit only one class in Sphinx?

For example:

```py
class Base1:
  pass

class Base2:
  pass

class MyCls(Base1, Base2):
  pass
```

Here I want to inherit docs of only `Base1` class and it's adding `Base2` too.
How do I make it inherit only `Base1` docs?